# What items can be created using Chem Fluid and Strong Chem Fluid?

Tags: resident-evil-7

There is a trophy/achievement that requires you too create *all* items that can be made using either Chem Fluid or Strong Chem Fluid:

> **1st Place at the Science Fair**
>
> Create all items that contain Chem Fluid and Strong Chem Fluid

What is the full list of items that can be created to unlock this?

In addition, I would be interested to know if any of them *don't* appear it the 'Combine Menu' which so far has been hinting on what items can be made by combining items in my inventory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [guide](http://gameranx.com/features/id/90098/article/resident-evil-7-biohazard-all-chem-fluids-drugs-crafting-item-locations/), there are a total of eight recipes:

> There are 8 recipes in RE7 — 4 Chem Fluid combos, and 4 Strong Chem
> Fluid combos.
>
> **Chem Fluid Recipes**
>
> - Chem Fluid + Herb = x1 First Aid Med
> - Chem Fluid + Gunpowder = x10 Handgun Ammo
> - Chem Fluid + Solid Fuel = x100 Burnen Fuel
> - Chem Fluid + Supplements = x1 Psychostimulants
>
> **Strong Chem Fluid Recipes**
>
> - Strong Chem Fluid + Herb = x1 Strong First Aid Med
> - Strong Chem Fluid + Gunpowder = x10 Enhanced Handgun Ammo
> - Strong Chem Fluid + Solid Fuel = x2 Flame Rounds
> - Strong Chem Fluid + Supplements = x2 Neuro Rounds

Basically, the Strong Chem Fluid recipes are the same as the Chem Fluid ones except you substitute in Strong  Chem Fluid to make a different item.  The guide also seems to suggest that you can make these by combining the items in your inventory (I'm not sure if that's what you mean by the crafting menu - I don't own the game... yet).  It also lists some of the locations where you can find some of the materials.

Comment: Looks like that guide only lists 3 Strong Chem Fluid... I wonder if that means the trophy takes into account multiple play-throughs

Comment: @musefan The guide also says _you can sometimes find special Separating Agent items — by combining these with any item in your inventory, you can break that item down to gain a crafting component and a Chem Fluid. Depending on the item, you might even get a Strong Chem Fluid._  It sounds like you can break down items to get both kinds of fluid as well as some other components.  It also doesn't appear to list all locations yet since the game is fairly new.

Answer (score 0):

All chemical fluid recipes appear in the menu, however, there are recipes that do not appear in the combine menu, such as 10 handgun ammo and 1 gunpowder, yielding 5 enhanced handgun ammo.

Comment: The second part of this answer doesn't really have anything to do with the question.